# started 'http-server' using command prompt its running but not working

Tags: html, reactjs, http, server, httpserver

I don't know if this is good place to ask this question but i just started studying reactjs and stuck in the beginning, here is the question.

I have installed node and Installed `http-server` from the `npm` command on the command prompt `npm install -g http-server` and went to the directory where is my static files and run command `http-server` and then to the browser hit `localhost:8081`.

Nothing happens/shows on browser but on command prompt it shows that its running and working properly, everytime i refresh browser then it shows on command prompt working. So why nothing happens on browser ?

here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
     <div id="example">
  
     </div>
  
  <script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(
          <h1>Something</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
  
 
  
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors on the browser console? Posting your reactjs code helps.

Comment: @Pavan there is no any errors on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is an ongoing issue with `http-server`. However, we can fix this using [this](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/525#issuecomment-489222044) tweak.

Try accessing your file in localhost with the filename after running `http-server` command.

For example, if your file name is `somefile.html`, try accessing this file like `http://localhost:8081/somefile.html`

Comment: this is error message i got on browser : This page isn’t working localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Comment: @waleedd32 I've updated my answer. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: it worked thanks but why it does not work like this : localhost:8081 ? and do you know any other way doing this instead of 'http-server' ?

Comment: @waleedd32 as per my understanding, there is an incompatibility issue with http-server version. It can be solved by downgrading the version of `http-server` using this command -  `npm install -g http-server@0.9.0`

Comment: why i need to refresh localhost everytime, isnt react automatic ? just saving and it should show it there without refresh

Comment: You will need to follow [these steps](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started) if you are configuring your react app in such a way you want to see the changes on the fly.

Comment: why i have been downvoted ? this was proper question

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an alternative/easy way to set up a react application without having to worry about the messy configuration settings from the beginning, then I recommend using facebooks [create-react-app starter code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

I realize this does not help you if you wished to learn the setup process, but for jumping right into react routing and learning that it is a great resource! I start most of my web-applications using this. It can also be easily modified to [implement express](https://dev.to/loujaybee/using-create-react-app-with-express) for when you delve even further into the world of web-dev. I believe the starter code is also set up with web-pack and supports hot-loading, so any changes you make will automatically be refreshed/reflected after hitting save and you do not need to restart/republish to the server!

On top of that, [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484243900) is also a great resource for learning react, the DOM, JS, Express, and the like. I read and worked through the last edition (published 2017?) and found it super useful, hopefully this newer edition holds the same reputation.

Web-pack in itself is another large topic, and I endorse you to read up on it's capabilities, functions, high level design/implementation and the like as it is really interesting! Happy transpiling!